# Displaying numbers not convert correct

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to convert some numbers.

Current out put of `$this->byte_convert($count)` is `460.80 KB` but it should display like `0.04 GB`

How can I display numbers like that?

```
$quota = imap_get_quotaroot($mbox, "INBOX");

$message = $quota['MESSAGE'];

$percentage = ($count / $message['limit']) * 100;

echo $this->gb_convert($count) . " (" . round($percentage) . "%) of " . $this->byte_convert($message['limit']) . " used";

function byte_convert($size) {
    # size smaller then 1kb
    if ($size < 1024) return $size . ' Byte';
    # size smaller then 1mb
    if ($size < 1048576) return sprintf("%4.2f KB", $size/1024);
    # size smaller then 1gb
    if ($size < 1073741824) return sprintf("%4.2f MB", $size/1048576);
    # size smaller then 1tb
    if ($size < 1099511627776) return sprintf("%4.2f GB", $size/1073741824);
    # size larger then 1tb
    else return sprintf("%4.2f TB", $size/1073741824);
}
```

#### Update

I made a function like

```
public function gb_convert($size) {
    return sprintf("%4.2f GB", $size/1073741824);
}
```

But the out put is 0.00

```
$count = 471858;

echo $this->gb_convert($count) . " (" . round($percentage) . "%) of " . $this->byte_convert($message['limit']) . " used";
```

Full output of echo

```
0.00 GB (0%) of 2.00 GB used
```

Comment: What is `$count`'s value?

Comment: @MehdiBounya `471858` when converted using function `460.80 KB`

Comment: Why are you expecting `0.04 GB`? the code is doing what it was told, if smaller than `1048576` return it as KB

Comment: Remove all the ifs(), keep the part that says return in GB, and delete the else. Done

Comment: 460 kB is ~0.000046 GB. If you round to two decimals 0.00 is correct result.

Comment: Isn't .04 GB 40000 KB? 0.0004608 GB is what 460.80 KB is... and I doubt you want to display all those leading zeros to a user. From a ux perspective as a user I rather see the kb number, then the mb number, and so on until my data gets into the gigabytes. Otherwise if its less than a gig just say 'less than a gig'

Comment: Almost everything I need lately, packagist has a package for that. Loving it: https://packagist.org/packages/brianium/nomnom

Comment: @Alex Thanks, it was typo. Also, I agree with you that units should be presented to end user with relation to scaling of amount (I.E. B, kB, MB, GB...).